# Manifest is not valid json Error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to update my extension but I get following error message. Message clear but there is no line 30. What is the problem?

[image]

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "IdeaShop Information",
    "description": "IdeaShop siteleri ile ilgili bilgileri gosterir",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "IdeaShop Information",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Directory Structure**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be an extra `]` at the end.

---

You can validate your json file at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thank you Toni Toni Chopper!

Answer (score 0):

An extra square bracket at the last but one line caused the error. The line number displayed in such message is not correct.